# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') from json.results

Tags: javascript

Error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
at Object.handler (C:\Windows\System32\C.C-Md\plugins\charainfo.js:7:70)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async Object.handler (C:\Windows\System32\C.C-Md\handler.js:515:25)

code :

```
let fetch = require('node-fetch')
let handler = async(m, { conn, text }) => {
  if (!text) throw `Masukkan query!`
  let res = await fetch(global.API('https://api.jikan.moe', '/v4/characters', { q: text }))
  if (!res.ok) throw await res.text()
  let json = await res.json()
  let { name, nicknames, url, image_url, about, type } = json.results[0]
let charaingfo = ` *Name:* ${name}
 *Nickname:* ${nicknames}
 *Link*: ${url}
 *About*: ${about}`

  conn.sendFile(m.chat, image_url, '', charaingfo, m)
}
handler.help = ['character <nama>']
handler.tags = ['internet']
handler.command = /^(chara|character)$/i

module.exports = handler
```

#### Expected JSON Payload

```
{"pagination":{"last_visible_page":1,"has_next_page":false,"current_page":1,"items":{"count":1,"total":1,"per_page":25}},"data":[{"mal_id":417,"url":"https:\/\/myanimelist.net\/character\/417\/Lelouch_Lamperouge","images":{"jpg":{"image_url":"https:\/\/cdn.myanimelist.net\/images\/characters\/8\/406163.jpg"},"webp":{"image_url":"https:\/\/cdn.myanimelist.net\/images\/characters\/8\/406163.webp","small_image_url":"https:\/\/cdn.myanimelist.net\/images\/characters\/8\/406163t.webp"}},"name":"Lelouch Lamperouge","name_kanji":"\u30eb\u30eb\u30fc\u30b7\u30e5\u30fb\u30e9\u30f3\u30da\u30eb\u30fc\u30b8","nicknames":["Lelouch vi Britannia","Zero","Lulu","Black Prince","The Demon Emperor"],"favorites":156830,"about":"Age: 17 (first season), 18 (second season)\nDate of Birth:  December 5, 1999 a.t.b. (Sagittarius)\nBlood Type: A\nNationality: Britannian\nHeight: 178 cm (5'10\")\nWeight: 56 kg (123 lbs)\nOccupation: Student, Terrorist, Knightmare Pilot, Politician, Emperor, Prince\nAllegiance: Order of the Black Knights\nPosition: Leader of the Black Knights\nKnightmare: Sutherland, Burai, Gawain, Shinkirou\n\nLelouch vi Britannia (\u30eb\u30eb\u30fc\u30b7\u30e5\u30fb\u30f4\u30a3\u30fb\u30d6\u30ea\u30bf\u30cb\u30a2, Rur\u016bshu Vui Buritania) is the main protagonist of the anime\/manga series Code Geass. He is the Eleventh Prince of the Holy Britannian Empire and the son of the 98th Emperor of Britannia, Charles zi Britannia.\n\nLelouch is a very clever individual who is also calm, sophisticated, and arrogant due to his aristocratic upbringing. While at school, Lelouch conducts himself as a friendly, likable, and often an easygoing student. However, this is a mask to hide his true nature. While as Zero, his true nature is expressed. His charisma and beliefs in justice gain him the trust and respect of many soldiers and leaders.\n\nHe is known for having a very stoic personality. He never cared about schoolwork, seeing the entire thing as trivial, even though his high intelligence would make it easy for him. He enjoys seeking out challenges, often playing chess against the nobility. In general, Lelouch takes most day-to-day affairs with open disinterest, often not even noticing the affection of others, especially Shirley, his classmate. He has a strong dislike for nobles, viewing them as tepid and \"overprivileged parasites.\"\n\nMany characters have noted that Lelouch is entirely selfish, as his desire to remake the world into what he wants it to become from his desire to avenge his mother's apparent death and Nunnally's sake. However, in time, he realizes that this goal is not just for them but also the entire world.\n\nDespite his cold, calculating demeanor and ruthlessness in battle, he can be a rather compassionate person to his friends and loved ones. To Nunnally, he is a loving older brother, and to Suzaku, a loyal friend, although the two are enemies. Lelouch, at first glance, seems to have relatively little concern for the well-being of his subordinates, but in reality, he does care about them, seeing them as valuable allies.\n\n\nCharacter Background (as Lelouch):\n\nCharacter Background (as Zero):\n\nFirst Season:\n\nSecond Season:\n\n\nGeass:\nLelouch's Geass, bestowed upon him by C.C., gives him \"The Power of Absolute Obedience,\" allowing him to plant commands within a person's mind upon eye contact in a manner comparable to hypnosis. Activation of his Geass is visually represented by the manifestation of a Geass Sigil in his left eye. Commands dictated are written into the minds of the designated targets, the Sigil projecting him from his eye to theirs.\n\nOf all the Geass abilities in the series, Lelouch's has been explored the most and also seems to have the most restrictions, and side effects of any Geass introduced:(Source: Code Geass Wiki, Villains Wiki, Heroes Wiki, Anime and Manga Universe Wiki)"}]}
```

how to fix it, thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Add `console.log(json)` after `let json = await res.json()` and tell us what you see so have more information to help you :)

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'log')
changed error

Comment: No, not `await res.json().console.log(json)`! That's not correct. Just put `console.log(json)` in a separate line after. Like this: `let json = await res.json();` ** NEW LINE ** `console.log(json)`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at Object.handler (C:\Windows\System32\C.C-Md\plugins\charainfo.js:8:70)
its still like that

Comment: that results should be like this https://api.jikan.moe/v4/characters?q=lelouch
what should i change

Comment: The `console.log(json)` should be before `let { name, nicknames, url, image_url, about, type } = json.results[0]`

Comment: Ok the json object should have a data object inside of it not results, so try accessing that as I show in my answer.

Comment: it work, but cant send a image file, only send a .bin file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok given the JSON you expected, change how you access the data:

`let { name, nicknames, url, image_url, about, type } = json.data[0]`

Comment: it work, but cant send a image file

Comment: it only send a .bin file

Comment: how to resolve?

Comment: @Alvino Sorry, I don't know why it is uploading a bin file but not an image file. I think that is a completely different issue? HTTP should treat both the same way, so maybe it is something related to what's happening on the server

Comment: i see on images have [object object]

Comment: And the bin files, what do you see? Can you create a new question detailing the issue?

Comment: nothing, its only 0 bytes file